# List data is disappear

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm not sure its a problem or not, i use scrapy crawl data and save it.

I can save my list data as well. For example `movieDate`
[image]

Here is my way:

```
def parse(self, response): 

# i use yield Request to another function prase_page
i = 1000
        dataLen = len(response.xpath('//div[@class="release_foto"]'))
        photoNodes = response.xpath('//div[@class="release_foto"]')
        for photoNode in photoNodes:
            contentHref = photoNode.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
            yield Request(contentHref, callback=self.parse_page, priority = i, dont_filter=True)
            i -= 1
            photoHref = photoNode.xpath('.//a/img/@src').extract_first()
            moviePhotoArray.append(photoHref)

        detailDict.update({
             'cnName': cnNameArray,
             'enName': enNameArray,
             'movieContent': movieContentArray,
             'versionType': versionTypeArray,
             'movieStyle': movieStyleArray,
             'releasedTime': releasedTimeArray,
             'moviePhoto': moviePhotoArray,
             'movieDate': movieDateArray,
             'movieTime': movieTimeArray,
             'movieStills': movieStillsArray,
             'movieActorCn': movieActorCnArray,
             'imdbScore': imdbArray,
             'rottenScore': rottenArray,
             'videoId': videoIdArray,
             'movieActorPhoto': movieActorPhotoArray})
        print 'Test enNameArray=>'
        print ', '.join(enNameArray)
        print 'Test movieDateArray=>'
        print ', '.join(movieDateArray)
```

I found that i can't get the movieDateArray value. Its print empty although when i save it to database it has value.

Here is my print `movieDateArray` is empty:

```
Test enNameArray=>
Pacific Rim Uprising, Tomb Raider, Ready Player One
Test movieDateArray=>
```

I find my global list all of under the function is empty:

```
def parse_page(self, response):

        global movieContentArray, countLen, dataLen
        global movieDateArray, movieTimeArray, movieStillsArray, movieStyleArray, movieActorCnArray, movieActorPhotoArray
        movieContent = response.xpath('//div[@class="gray_infobox_inner"]/span/text()').extract_first()
        movieDate = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/span/text()')[0].extract()
        movieTime = response.xpath('//*[@class="movie_intro_info_r"]/span/text()')[1].extract()
        movieStills = response.xpath('//ul[@class="trailer_list imglist"]//div[@class="foto"]/img/@src').extract()
        movieStyle = response.xpath('//div[@class="level_name_box"]//div[@class="level_name"]/a/text()').extract()
        movieActorCn = response.xpath('//ul[@class="trailer_list alist starlist"]/li/a//div[@class="fotoinner"]/img/@title').extract()
        movieActorPhoto = response.xpath('//ul[@class="trailer_list alist starlist"]/li/a//div[@class="fotoinner"]/img/@src').extract()
        movieContentArray.append(movieContent)
        movieDateArray.append(movieDate)
        movieTimeArray.append(movieTime)
        movieStillsArray.append(movieStills)
        movieStyleArray.append(movieStyle)
        movieActorCnArray.append(movieActorCn)
        movieActorPhotoArray.append(movieActorPhoto)
        # i can print the value here
        print 'Test=>inside movieDateArray=>',movieDateArray

        countLen += 1
        if countLen == dataLen:
            yield tainan
```

I have no idea why the list `movieDateArray` is empty. Because i save the list to database it is not empty, but when i try to `print` it or `for in` it is empty.

It is so strange. Some one can tell me what step i miss it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I beleive the issue is that each time you call `parse_page` you define a new global variable called `movieDateArray`. Perhaps during the last call this variable is initialized to `None` and that's why you don't print anything. Try debugging by printing `movieDateArray` in each loop iteration

Comment: Hmm... i type `print 'loop movieDateArray=>',movieDateArray` under my `for in` yield Request .  It will run three times and I see three empty list  [] [] []  .  If i remove global movieDateArray under `parse_page`  . The list still show three []  []  []  . What a nightmare...

Comment: This is indeed weird... I cannot reproduce the issue without having specific details regarding the DB, website etc., but in general, I would offer 2 improvements to your code: 1. Do not use `global` variables unless necessary, try to use scoped variables instead in you code. 2. when using generators, you should probably define them in another function and then iterate over that

Comment: It will be more complicated for me to use second suggestion.  Cuz i crawl one page data and then crawl it's content data . There are a lots of variable.

Comment: I find that no matter what i save the value to dictionary or list in the function `parse_page`, i print them in `parse` function will be empty.